# Android: Service shows AlertDialog only for the Administration User

Tags: android, service, android-alertdialog, administration

I write a Service that listen with a Server-Tread on a Network Port for a Message. After the Service received a Message-Text, it shows a AlertDialog with this Message-Text. The Service started on Boot with the “action.BOOT_COMPLETED”.
I installed this Service as the Adminstration-User and then restarted the Device.

When I log in as the Administration-User all work fine.

But when I log in as another normal User and send a Message from another device, no Message is shown. After this, when I log out and log in as the Administration-User I can see the Message that was send before.

I tried to use different context’s: “this” or “getApplicationContext()” or “getBaseContext()”, but it is always the same Problem.

I also tried to start a simple Activity instead of the AlertDialog, but with the same Problem, the Activity starts only by the Administration-User.

Thanks for your Help,
Martin

---

TestService.java

```
public class TestService extends Service {

    Handler updateConversationHandler;
    Thread serverThread = null;
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    Boolean commThreadRum;
    Context context;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        updateConversationHandler = new Handler();

        context = this;
        //context = getApplicationContext();
        //context = getBaseContext();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        serverThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
        serverThread.start();

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    private class ServerThread implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            Socket socket;
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5678);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                    if (serverSocket != null) {
                        socket = serverSocket.accept();
                        CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
                        commThreadRum = true;
                        new Thread(commThread).start();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {
        private Socket clientSocket;
        private BufferedReader input;

        private CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket) {
            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
            try {
                this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() & commThreadRum) {
                try {
                    String read = input.readLine();
                    if (read !=null && !read.isEmpty()) {
                        updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(read));
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class updateUIThread implements Runnable {
        private String msg;

        private updateUIThread(String read) {
            this.msg = read;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (msg != null && !msg.isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    dlgAlert.setTitle("Nachricht");
                    dlgAlert.setMessage(msg);
                    dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = dlgAlert.create();
                    alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
                    alertDialog.show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("NACHRICHT ", "ERROR ", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

OnBootBroadcastReceiver.java

```
public class OnBootBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), TestService.class);
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name=".OnBootBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service
            android:name=".TestService"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
        </service>
    </application>
```